# Powershell HTML body converting issue

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have a script that reads a list on a Sharepoint 2019 OnPremise site. The idea is to capture certifcates that are about to expire.

Problem is I can't conver it properly to a html-table however I do. I done converting before but not in PNP and with camel querys.

Script:

```
$smtpserver = "-"
$mailsender ="-"
$mailReceiver = "-"
$mailSubject = "Certificates about to expire"

$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
</style>
"@


    Import-Module "C:\PNP\SharePointPnPPowerShell2019\3.6.1902.2\SharePointPnPPowerShell2019.psd1"
    if ($cred -eq $null)
    { 
    $cred = Get-Credential
    }
    Connect-PnPOnline "-" -Credentials $cred
    $list = Get-PnPList "-"
        
$listitems = Get-PnPListItem -List $list -Query "<View><Query><Where><Lt><FieldRef Name='Utg_x00e5_r' Type='DateTime'/><Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='60'/></Value></Lt></Where></Query></View>" | Select-object {$_["Title"], $_["Farm"], $_["Server"] , $_["Utg_x00e5_r"]} | ConvertTo-Html -Head $header | Out-String


Send-MailMessage -From $mailsender -to $mailReceiver -subject $mailSubject -body ($listitems | Out-String) -SmtpServer $smtpServer -Port 25 -BodyAsHtml
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the problem? What does the resulting HTML look like (please add sample output [to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72603006/edit)), and how does that differ from what you expected?

Comment: It's unclear if it's a sharepoint issue or a powershell issue. Do have issues to retrieve data or to format data as Html ? It would help if you create a [minimal]

Comment: I can't add the result as it's sensitive. But It's not split up, so it's all in one column instead of 4, as you see in the script I'm taking out 4 columns from the sharepoint list and therefore want the same in the table, so Title, Farm, Server and Utg_x00e5_r.

Comment: t's a powershell issue, it won't format it to a proper table split up, it would do it with format-table, but convering it to html wont do it. I used a different @header for previous scripts as well, tried a bunch so it would not be anything with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Select-Object` statement currently creates objects with only 1 property, hence the single column in your output.

Change it to something like:

```
...| Select-Object @{Name='Title';Expression={$_["Title"]}},@{Name='Farm';Expression={$_["Farm"]}},@{Name='Server';Expression={$_["Server"]}},@{Name='Utg_x00e5_r';Expression={$_["Utg_x00e5_r"]}} |ConvertTo-Html ...
```

... which will create objects with *4 separate properties*, which will in turn translate into a 4-column HTML table

Comment: Mathias, thats right, you just reminded me I had similar problem long ago with same solution, works like a charm! Thank you.